# I want to link one model field to another

Tags: django, django-models

I want to be able to show unit_price field on the orderItems model the same price as the photograph model.

**OrderItem**

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Photograph, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, 
                                decimal_places=2,
                                validators=[MinValueValidator(1)]
                                )
    order_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'ID: %s' % (self.order.id)
```

**Photograph model**

```
class Photograph(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False,
                              upload_to="photos/", default="default.png")
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, default="")
    description = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    slug = models.SlugField()

    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, 
                                decimal_places=2,
                                validators=[MinValueValidator(1)]
                                )
    inventory = models.IntegerField() 
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    promotions = models.ManyToManyField(Promotion, blank=True)
```

Comment: Just save the price when you create your OrderItem object.

Comment: If this is the case, could you post a detailed answer?

Comment: Show/post code of how you save/create an OrderItem.

Comment: I figured it out @Marco thank you, your comment was more valuable than I thought

Answer (score 0):

orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product, unit_price=product.price)

**ADDED unit_price=product.price to the above code so my product price would link with my unit price.**